# What to do if you are on the reserve list of one grad program and get accepted to another?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I applied to a graduate program in mathematics at university A. I went to their oral interview, and could not give some proofs that they asked for. As far as I know, university A has two lists: main and reserve. I am not declined, so I think that they put me on their reserve list because there were people who did better than me in the interview. I also applied to university B that I would like to study math at, and did great at their interview.

I'd prefer to choose university A. So, should I pick university A on whose reserve list I am, or university B which put me on their main list?

Comment: Before you make any decision (which is essentially yours), do confirm with the first school that you are, in fact, on their reserve list. Not receiving a refusal letter seems a bit risky to conclude that you are, as an administrative oversight is at least conceivable.

Comment: Do you want to gamble? You need to ascertain your risk aversion or friendliness to decide this. And, if you are risk friendly, take into account what you will do if university A does *not* accept you and you gave up position at university B.